# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'testName' of undefined at Object.eval

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, browser, ide

I have `angular` & `spring boot` running on my system. 
When routing to last page, it is expected to formulate values being passed from previous route. But I am receiving error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pName' of undefined at Object.eval

Other team member are not facing this issue on their system. I am not sure if it's browser issue or something else.

Things I tried:

- Cleared browser Cache
- ReImported the application
- Tried in another browser

Here is the code where "pName" is used.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````html
HTML1 : 

<table class="row page-row align-items-start col-12">
                  <tr>
                   <td>Name:</td>
                    <td>{{projectBasicInfo['Address']['pName']}}</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td>Address:</td>
                     <td>{{BasicInfo['Address']['pstreet']}}
                      , {{BasicInfo['Address']['pcity']}}
                       , {{BasicInfo['Address']['pstate']} 
                       {{BasicInfo['Address']['pzip']}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Term:</td>
                   <td>{{BasicInfo['eDate']}} to {{BasicInfo['eDate']}}</td>
                    </tr>
 </table>
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

HTML 2:

    <div class="list-group-item">
                <h5>Name</h5>
                <p>{{quoteResult.pAddress.pName}}</p>
     </div>

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
HTML3:

<div class="list-group-item">
              <h6><b>Name</b></h6>
              <a>{{Result.pAddress.pName}}</a>
</div>
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

HTML4:

<div class="row page-row align-items-start">
   <div class="col-6">
    <input [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': pName.touched && pName.invalid}" class="form-control" formControlName="pName" type="text"  maxlength="70">
                                <span *ngIf="pName.touched && pName.invalid" 
    class="text-danger">This field is required</span>
    </div>
</div>
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Service: 

pAddress: this.fb.group({
        pName: ['', Validators.required],
        pstreet: ['', Validators.required],
        pcity: ['', Validators.required],
        pstate: ['', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.StateRequirements]],
        pcounty: ['', Validators.required]
      }),
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

ts file:
get pName(): AbstractControl { return this.pageData.formGroup.get('pAddress').get('pName'); }
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: It is impossible to help you, without knowing the application, its code and the environment you try to run it in. So your question is very unclear. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If it is code thing It should not run on any of the machine right? @SamuelPhilipp

Comment: Can you share your code snippet. or Try to create another angular project and replicate same scenario over there, see if you still face same issue. If yes, share that project, at least. 

Comment: @SumitRamteke Added

Comment: 2 things. one double quote is missing near `formControlName="pName`. 2nd are you using `[formGroup]="pAddress"` with parent `form` tag? Just wanted to make sure

Comment: @SumitRamteke Sorry!! I missed to close that double quote while pasting that here.But, It is there in my code.  And Yes I am using form group this way :

<div [formGroup]="pageData.formGroup.get('pAddress')">

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [safe navigational operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)

```
<input [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': pName?.touched && pName?.invalid}" 
       class="form-control" formControlName="pName" 
       type="text"  maxlength="70">

<span *ngIf="pName?.touched && pName?.invalid" 
      class="text-danger">This field is required</span>
```

notice question mark (`?`) sign just before dot operator

Comment: Tried that but, no change in my application. 

But I found the issue in my app.  That is not regarding angular.But, I had wrong data type for phone number field. So entering one range of values throws an error. I fixed that changing the data type. 

Thanks every one!!

Comment: appreciate your response